# Undefined control sequence \reset@newl@bel

Tags: errors

```
\relax 
\reset@newl@bel
\select@language{english}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}REQUIREMENTS}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1}User Authentication}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.1.1}Create Account}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.1.2}Sign in}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2}Preference}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.2.1}Input initial preference}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.2.2}Analysis with collaborative filtering algorithm}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.2.3}Recommendation of music based on genre}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.3}My Page}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.3.1}My profile}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {2.3.1.1}Profile picture}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {2.3.1.2}Profile music}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.3.2}Posting with music}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.3.3}Edit / delete post}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.3.4}Playlist}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.3.5}My box}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.3.6}Hash tag}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {2.3.6.1}Search}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {2.3.6.2}Following}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.4}Music Feed}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.4.1}Note Button}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.4.2}Save to My Box}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.4.3}Comment}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.4.4}Report}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5}Friends}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.5.1}Search}{3}}mendation of friends}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.6}Recommendation Playlist based on mood}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.7}Chatting}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.8}Message Box
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.5.2}Recom}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.9}Question Board}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.10}Frequently uploaded Music TOP10}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.11}Voting function}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Development}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1}Choice of software development platform}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2}Software in use}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}Specifications}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.1}User Authentication}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.1.1}Create Account}{4}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Sample register page}}{4}}
\newlabel{fig1}{{1}{4}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.1.2}Sign in}{5}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Sample login page}}{5}}
\newlabel{fig2}{{2}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.2}Preference}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.2.1}Input initial preference}{5}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3}{\ignorespaces Collecting user preference data with Google Forms}}{5}}
\newlabel{fig3}{{3}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.2.2}Analysis with collaborative filtering algorithm}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.2.3}Recommendation of music based on genre}{8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.3}My Page}{8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.3.1}My profile}{8}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4}{\ignorespaces My profile}}{8}}
\newlabel{fig4}{{4}{8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {4.3.1.1}Profile picture}{8}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {5}{\ignorespaces Sample profile pictures}}{8}}
\newlabel{fig5}{{5}{8}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {4.3.1.2}Profile music}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {4.3.1.3}Posting with music}{9}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6}{\ignorespaces An example post which includes a song}}{9}}
\newlabel{fig6}{{6}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.4}Friends}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.4.1}Search}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.4.2}Recommendation of friends}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.5}Recommendation Playlist based on mood}{9}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {7}{\ignorespaces Sample page }}{9}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{7}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.6}Chatting}{9}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {8}{\ignorespaces Public Chatroom }}{10}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{8}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {9}{\ignorespaces Private Chatroom }}{10}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{9}{10}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.7}Message Box}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {10}{\ignorespaces The location of message box }}{10}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{10}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {11}{\ignorespaces The writing box of Message Box}}{10}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{11}{10}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.8}Question Board}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {12}{\ignorespaces The Question Board }}{11}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{12}{11}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {13}{\ignorespaces The entire view of the post in the Question Board }}{11}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{13}{11}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.9}Music Top 10}{11}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {14}{\ignorespaces The current Top 10 Playlist }}{11}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{14}{11}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.10}Voting function}{11}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {15}{\ignorespaces The example of voting }}{11}}
\newlabel{overflow}{{15}{11}}
\bibcite{IEEEhowto:kopka}{1}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{Appendix\nobreakspace  A: Proof of the First Zonklar Equation}{12}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{Appendix\nobreakspace  B}{12}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{References}{12}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{Biographies}{12}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{Michael Shell}{12}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{John Doe}{12}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{Jane Doe}{12}}
```

Comment: This is an `.aux` file but nothing else

Comment: Hi and welcome, if this is not purely spam, we'd really like to see some real question here.

Answer (score 17):

Very likely you are using package `acronym` and have updated it recently.
Older version have used `\reset@newl@bel` in the `.aux` files. Recently this was renamed to `\AC@reset@newl@bel`. Older `.aux` files are causing now the undefined command error. Either you can ignore the error or delete the `.aux` files. The error should be gone, when the `.aux` files are rewritten with the new version of `acronym`.